# What is the MacBook trackpad input latency?

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

What is the expected input latency for MacBook trackpads?

I would like to know for the 15" 2015 MacBook Pro model, and the newest MacBook models.

I have tried searching but am really struggling to find official or measured figures. I just keep coming across "help me with my trackpad lag" posts.

Have the trackpads' latencies ever been revealed officially by Apple, or been measured and released by users?

Comment: What do you want the number for? - I.e. what are you going to use it for? - If I know that, I might be able to help you. Right now, I expect that you won't be able to get any answers I'm afraid.

Comment: @jksoegaard compare it with mouse input latencies

Comment: For the purpose of?

Comment: @jksoegaard having a quotable figure as to how much faster/how similar its input latency is to a mouse's.

Comment: We’re going in cirkles I feel. I can’t really give good suggestions on how you measure that without knowing what it is going to be used for. However an easy start would be to use a slow motion video capturing iPhone to capture footage of the pad and the display at the same time. However it has a pretty measuring error, and you can’t really measure anything below approx 5 ms

Comment: pretty large* ...

Comment: @jksoegaard: "What do you want the number for?" Why are you asking this question? Isn't it obvious why they want it? They're experiencing an observable difference in latency between their trackpad and their mouse. I, like them, am experiencing the same—in my case, my trackpad feels slower.  I would like to know whether this is real, imagined, or something in between. Why would I want to know this? Because, if it's real, then a conversation can begin: why is there a difference, and how can it be addressed? If it's imagined, then I can convince myself psychologically not to be annoyed by it.

Comment: No, it’s not obvious. Depending on what you need the number for, there’s different ways of measuring that have pros/cons - and there’s different ways of minimizing latency that again have pros/cons. If your purpose is only to figure out if you’re imagining a difference so that you can convince yourself it is not there, then just do that from the get go and you have an easy fix. Alternatively you could just make slow down the device you perceive as the slowest until you feel you have the same latency.

Comment: I'm not observing any lag. I just want to know what it is.